# Tracking mobile app installations with Google Tag Manager

Tags: android, ios, app-store, tracking, google-tag-manager

How can we track mobile app downloads with GTM?

- Are there some native events (SDK) sent to GTM?
- If not, can I ask the developer to get some event sent upon installation? Or first run?

The goal of the exercise is to fire DoubleClick tags upon successful app download.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can track mobile apps using firebase SDK with GTM for Android and iOS:

https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v5/

https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/ios/v5/

And yes, there are a lot of default events already configured, you can see a quick overview in this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iT6EaIwtonY&index=2&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLmOF_07IayrTntevxtbUxDL

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful.